# animate image position from its position instead of page's cordenades

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, absolute

```
$('#container img')
                .clone()
                .appendTo('#container')
                .css({'position' : 'absolute','z-index':9999,marginLeft:-100})
                .animate({opacity: 0.1, left: 200,top:200,height:420}, 1000, function() {
                    $(this).remove();
                     actualizar(iGal);

            });
```

Basicalli i want to move it 200px to left and 200 to bottom, 
but what happens is it gets moved to page cordenade 200px left and 200px bottom,

```
.css({'position','relative'});
```

instead, but then the position is not animed,

what am i missing? do i have to do it with offset?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use

```
...
.animate({opacity: 0.1, left: "+=200",top:"+=200",height:420}, 1000, function() {
...
```

then you add 200px to the x and y axis

Or you can detect the offset first:

```
var offset = {
    x: $('#container img').offset().left,
    y: $('#container img').offset().top
};

...
.animate({opacity: 0.1, left: offset.x+200,top: offset.y+200,height:420}, 1000, function() {
...
```

The jQuery `offset` function returns the offset from the browser windows top and left corner. There are another function called `position` which determinate the offset to the first parent element having `position` `relative` or `absolute`.

http://jsfiddle.net/UDb7V/

Comment: Thanks, was helpful for a quick animation project

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example. I tried to break it down with just the animation stuff. You can add back in more complexity.

HTML

```
<div id='#container'>
    <p>Text above the image</p>
    <img id='img' src='http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png' />
    <p>Text below the image</p>
    <button id='start'>Animate</button>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container { position: relative; }

#img { position: relative; }
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$('#start').click(function(){

    $('#img').animate({left:'100px', top:'100px'}, 1000, function(){
       alert('here');
    }); 

});
```

Here is a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cfrN2/1/

Hope this helps.

Bob